# Good way to handle running python script in background with Django?

Tags: python, django, celery

The task is to run a python script in background and put a webpage like "Your script is running now...back to you later" on submission of request, then download result page when the run is over. Celery seems a good choice but it sounds a overkill since only one script will run in the backend. Is there a simple way in Django to handle it?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: Does the user stay on this page until the script is finished? Does the page need to check on the status of the background task in case the user leaves the site and comes back? Use cases like that will determine if you can simply poll via Ajax for a database status change for example, or if you need something more robust.

Comment: The simple use case is rendering a page showing the script is running and rendering another page when the script is finished. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use python [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) built-in module. Correctly using Popen Objects you can start a process, see it's running status with `Popen.poll()`, wait for it to finish with `Popen.wait()` or even communicate with it or terminate it. So I guess you could have a variable in Django/Python that sets to `False` everytime you star a process and while that variable is False you can display a status on the site, once it finished you set the variable to `True` and do your stuff.

Comment: If you're gonna open subprocesses from within WSGI with a pipe open to communicate with it, it'll get killed as soon as your request terminates.

Comment: Thanks so much! I guess I understand the subprocess step. But in my view, how to return one page to indicate the script status when it is running and return another page of results when it is finished. I tried while loop, but it seems not working.